# Stopping a while loop mid-way - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, while-loop, break

What is the best way to stop a 'while' loop in Python mid-way through the statement? I'm aware of `break` but I thought using this would be bad practice.

For example, in this code below, I only want the program to print once, not twice...

```
variable = ""
while variable == "" :
    print("Variable is blank.")

    # statement should break here...

    variable = "text"
    print("Variable is: " + variable)
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about replacing the `while` with an `if`?

Comment: Why using `break` is a _bad practice here_ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break` is fine, although it is usually used conditionally. Used unconditionally, it raises the question of why a `while` loop is used at all:

```
# Don't do this
while condition:
    <some code>
    break
    <some unreachable code>

# Do this
if condition:
    <some code>
```

---

Used conditionally, it provides a way of testing the loop condition (or a completely separate condition) early:

```
while <some condition>:
    <some code>
    if <other condition>:
        break
    <some more code>
```

It is often used with an otherwise infinite loop to simulate the `do-while` statement found in other languages, so that you can guarantee the loop executes at least once.

```
while True:
    <some code>
    if <some condition>:
        break
```

rather than

```
<some code>
while <some condition>:
    <some code>
```